# Find number of substrings in binary string having equal 1's and 0's

Tags: algorithm

I came across the following question,

Find the total number of substrings in a string which contain equal number of 1's and 0's. Also the substring should have consecutive 0's followed by consecutive 1's or vice versa.

For example,

```
1010 - 10,01,10

1100110- 1100,10,0011,01,10.
```

My initial idea was to use a n^2 loop to find all substrings and then check if the condition is satisfied. Obviously there must be a better solution to this as I could not pass all cases.

Please suggest ideas to improve on this. Thanks.

Comment: You say "the substring should have consecutive 0's followed by consecutive 1's or vice versa." but your examples don't follow that guideline.  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: What I meant is that any substring should be counted only if it has a group of 0's followed by a group of 1's or a group of 1's followed by a group of 0's. for instance, in the 2 queries above, the valid substrings for 1010 would be 10,01,10 and the valid substrings for query 1100110 would be 1100,10,0011,01,10

Comment: Ah -- so `0110` isn't acceptable; got it.  You can divide the string at the middle; one half will be all 0s, and the other will be all 1s.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d suggest the following - iterating over you sequence for each consecutive sequence of 0’s or 1’s of length L(k) (except for the first one) add to the counter min(L(k), L(k-1)). The final value of the counter will be the number you’re looking for.

For your example 1100110

L = (2, 2, 2, 1)

And the sum is 2+2+1=5